# Density plot with python making a Diffraction pattern with Bessel Integrals but it wont stop running

Tags: python, matplotlib, density-plot, imshow, bessel-functions

I am trying to make a circular diffraction pattern,
which has a central spot surrounded by a series of rings.
It involves a Bessel integral to do it which is defined in the code.

My problems is that it takes too long like I waited 10 min for the code to run but didn't get anything to display. I understand it is because my Bessel integral has 1000 iterations per point can any one help with this ?

Am I on the right track?

I am trying to **self teach** myself python and computational physics via Mark Newmans book Computational Physics the exercise is 5.4 of Computational Physics.Here is a link to the chapter. It is on page 9.
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/cp/chapters/int.pdf

Here is the Image I am trying to make.

[image: concentric rings].

**My Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import math as mathy

#N = number of slicices 
#h = b-a/N 

def J(m,x): #Bessel Integral
    def f(theta):
        return (1/mathy.pi)*mathy.cos(m*theta - x*mathy.sin(theta)) #I replaced np. with mathy. for this line

    N = 1000
    A = 0
    a=0
    b=mathy.pi
    h = ((b-a)/N)

    for k in range(1,N,2):

        A +=  4*f(a + h*k)

    for k in range(2,N,2):

        A +=  2*f(a + h*k)

    Idx =  (h/3)*(A + f(a)+f(b))

    return Idx

def I(lmda,r): #Intensity
    k = (mathy.pi/lmda)    
    return ((J(1,k*r))/(k*r))**2

wavelength = .5        # microm meters
I0 = 1
points = 500           
sepration = 0.2  

Intensity = np.empty([points,points],np.float)

for i in range(points):
    y = sepration*i
    for j in range(points):
        x = sepration*j
        r = np.sqrt((x)**2+(y)**2)

        if r < 0.000000000001:
            Intensity[i,j]= 0.5 #this is the lim as r  -> 0, I -> 0.5
        else: 
            Intensity[i,j] = I0*I(wavelength,r)

plt.imshow(Intensity,vmax=0.01,cmap='hot')
plt.gray()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to run fine - if I reduce `N` down to 100 (from 1000) and the image size (`points`) down to 50 (from 500). I get the following image after around 4s of execution time:

[image]

Here's what we get when profiling your code with cProfile:

```
$ python -m cProfile -s time bessel.py | head -n 10
         361598 function calls (359660 primitive calls) in 3.470 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   252399    2.250    0.000    2.250    0.000 bessel.py:24(f)
     2499    0.821    0.000    3.079    0.001 bessel.py:23(J)
        1    0.027    0.027    3.472    3.472 bessel.py:15(<module>)
     2499    0.015    0.000    3.093    0.001 bessel.py:45(I)
        1    0.013    0.013    0.013    0.013 backend_macosx.py:1(<module>)
```

So it looks like most of your execution time is spent in `f`. You could possibly optimise this function, or alternatively try running your code using [PyPy](http://pypy.org/). PyPy is excellent at optimising this sort of thing. You need to install their version of numpy (see http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#). But PyPy completes your original code in 40s on my machine (with the plotting stuff removed).

**EDIT**

I haven't got plotlib installed in PyPy on my system, so I replaced your plt calls at the end with

```
#plt.imshow(Intensity,vmax=0.01,cmap='hot')
#plt.gray()
#plt.show()
np.savetxt('bessel.txt', Intensity)
```

And created a separate program that I execute with normal Python containing:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

Intensity = np.loadtxt('bessel.txt')

plt.imshow(Intensity,vmax=0.01,cmap='hot')
plt.gray()
plt.show()
```

This produces the image below with the following modifications to your code:

```
sepration = 0.008 # decrease separation

Intensity = np.empty([points,points],np.float)

for i in range(points):
    y = sepration*(i - points/2) # centre on image
    for j in range(points):
        x = sepration*(j - points/2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I replaced the np. with mathy., it runs a little faster. But Two Questions First if I use 500 points it makes the whole picture black how do I fix this. Second how do I center the circles

Comment: @FireFistAce see my latest edits, you just need to adjust `separation` (a value of 0.008 works for 500 points), and offset your `x` & `y` calculations by `i * points/2`

Comment: I did but I only get the central circle no rings around it, did you do some other modification as well?

Comment: @FireFistAce, no just those. Try varying `separation` perhaps

Comment: Ok just checked it my separation it was 0.002 not 0.008 it works fine now that I changed it to 0.008 thanks so much