# Python - Create animated matplotlib figure of circular interference pattern

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Similar to the interference pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879745/density-plot-with-python-making-a-diffraction-pattern-with-bessel-integrals-but), I would like to create an animation of this interference pattern changing as fringe transitions occur - ie as fringes emerge from the centre of the pattern and expand outwards.

Answer (score 0):

I know little about this but a quick google points you to this official matplotlib example which you can view here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html

Read that and see how you get on.